# Define a command that prints the first letter of its input argument

Tags: macros, arguments, definition

Is there a way to define a command or macro that outputs only the first letter of its argument?

Example: my name is Joaquim Brasil. I could define a macro `\def\WhatIsYourName#1{\@WhatIsYourName{#1}}` that stores my name and another one `\def\MyNameIs{\@WhatIsYourName}` that prints `Joaquim Brasil` whenever I do `\MyNameIs` in the body of my `tex` file. However, I sometimes need to print `B., Joaquim` since this is my signature.

So, my question is: **Is there a way to define a command, say `\MySignatureIs` that reads the value stored in `\MyNameIs` and outputs the signature in the way required above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by specifying the "shape" of the input using `\def`. For example, if you define

```
\def\@setinitials#1#2@{\def\@initials{#1}}
```

and then use `\@setinitials Joaquim@` then when `\@setinitials` is expanded `#1` is set to `J` and `#2` to `oaquim` so that `\@initials` is defined to be `J`. The key point is that the `@` at the end of the parameter specifications for `\@setinitials` tell TeX to set `#2` to be whatever follows `#1` up to the the next `@` character in the input stream. Of course, you do not want to use the command `\@setintials` "by hand", since you would always have to put the `@` character at the end, but by chaining a series of commands like this you can set it up so that the code

```
  \SetMyName{Joaquim Brasil}
  My name is \MyName.
  My abbreviated name is \myName.
  My abbreviated surname is \Myname.
```

produces

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@firstname{} % initialise all name variants
\def\@firstnameInitial{}
\def\@surnameInitial{}
\def\@surname{}
\def\@setsurnameinitial#1#2@{\def\@surnameInitial{#1}}
\def\@setinitial#1#2@{\def\@firstnameInitial{#1}}
\def\@setmyname#1 #2@{% space separates #1 and #2 up to @
  \def\@firstname{#1}% set first name
  \def\@surname{#2}%   set surname
  \@setinitial#1@%     set firstname initial
  \@setsurnameinitial#2@% set surname initial
}
\newcommand\SetMyName[1]{\@setmyname #1@}
\newcommand\MyName{\@firstname\space\@surname}
\newcommand\myName{\@firstnameInitial.~\@surname}
\newcommand\Myname{\@surnameInitial.,~\@firstname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \SetMyName{Joaquim Brasil}

  My name is \MyName.

  My abbreviated name is \myName.

  My abbreviated surname is \Myname.

\end{document}
```

A final caveat, this `\SetMyName` command will break if the name that it is given does not contain a space, such as `\SetMyName{Brasil}`. With a little more effort you could cope with this case too. It will also break if the name contains an `@` character. If you want something really robust then I would probably switch to using [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel).

Comment: Hi @Andrew thank you for the response. I tested the code and simply commented out the first four `\def`s. After compilation, no error occurred, so that I believe that these defs are not necessary. Do you agree?

Comment: @Brasil The first four `\def`'s initialise the macros that are used by the various my name macros. If you delete these and then use `\MyName`, `\Myname` or `\myName` without first using `\SetMyName` then you will get an error. These commands are not necessary if `\SetMyName` is always used. They are there only to stop a compilation problem in case of "user error".

Comment: Great! Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an expandable `expl3` implementation that copes with middle names, single names, and no forbidden characters :-)

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_brasil_name_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \WhatIsYourName { m }
  { \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_brasil_name_seq { ~ } {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \MyNameIs { }
  { \seq_use:Nn \g_brasil_name_seq { ~ } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \MySignatureIs { }
  {
    \__brasil_signature:ee
      { \seq_item:Nn \g_brasil_name_seq { 1 } }
      {
        \seq_use:Nn \g_brasil_name_seq { \s_stop } \s_stop
        \exp_not:N \q_nil \s_stop
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__brasil_signature:nn #1 #2
  {
    \exp_last_unbraced:No \__brasil_signature_aux:w
      { \use_none_delimit_by_s_stop:w #2 } #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__brasil_signature:nn { ee }
\cs_new:Npn \__brasil_signature_aux:w #1 \s_stop
  {
    \quark_if_nil:nF {#1}
      { \tl_head:n {#1}.,~ \__brasil_signature_aux:w }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\WhatIsYourName{Joaquim Brasil}

My name is \MyNameIs{} and my signature is \MySignatureIs.

\WhatIsYourName{Brasil}

My name is \MyNameIs{} and my signature is \MySignatureIs.

\WhatIsYourName{Joaquim Middle Name Brasil}

My name is \MyNameIs{} and my signature is \MySignatureIs.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry @PhelypeOleinik but I mistakenly upvoted your answer before testing it. I tried to compile, but I got a lot of errors and no output.

Comment: @Brasil I wouldn't post an answer that doesn't work (for me, at least :-). What errors (usually the first one is enough)? What TeX distribution do you have?

Comment: I am trying to compile in Overleaf, so that I cannot `Ctrl+C`. But I will try to type it here (sorry if I make any mistake):

`\MySignatureIs code ->\exp_args:Nee
               \_brasil_signature:nn{\seq_item:Nn\g_...
l.35 ...ameIs{} and my signature is \MySignatureIs

The control sequence at the end of the top line of your
error message was never \def'ed.`

Something like this...

Comment: @Brasil I changed so it works with TL'18.  With TL'17 or older you can do it expandably as well, but the code would need to change quite a lot.  Anyways, in Overleaf you can change the version of TeXLive by going to the Menu and then selecting a newer version.

Comment: Yes! Now it runs perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the TL version. I didn't know it. I am quite new to LaTeX. :-)